# заключить все слова страницы в тег span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в html странице все слова разделенные пробелами, которые видны в окне браузера, заключить в тег span?

Например, было:

```
<div>
Слово1 
<p>Слово2</p>
<button>Слово3 Слово4</button>
</div>
```

Стало:

```
<div>
 <span>Слово1</span>
 <p><span>Слово2</span></p>
 <button><span>Слово3</span> <span>Слово4</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем вам такое?

Comment: А можно при этом всю разметку снести и заново пересоздать?

Comment: А что делать со словами разделенными нескольким пробелам (переводами строк)? А что делать со знаками препинания?

Comment: Нужно бы более конкретное описание того, что у вас имеется и зачем вам необходимо из этого сделать то, что хотите. Может быть даже надо будет другую стратегию придумать. Или же как сказал Qwertiy - разметку поменять проще

Comment: разметку снести можно, главное чтобы она выглядела потом также)

Comment: Переводы строк и знаки препинание не учитываются, в любом случае в тексте после знаков препинания будут пробелы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body *').each(function() {
    element = $(this);
    node = element[0].childNodes;

    for (key in node) {
      if (node[key].nodeName == '#text') {
        if ($.trim(node[key].nodeValue).length == 0)
          continue;

        arrayText = $.trim(node[key].nodeValue).split(' ');
        returnText = '';

        for (index in arrayText) {
          if (arrayText[index] != '') {
            returnText += '<span>' + arrayText[index] + '</span> ';
          }
        }
        
        returnText = returnText.substr(0, returnText.length - 1);

        $(node[key]).wrap("<p />").parent().html(returnText).contents().unwrap();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Слово1
  <p>Слово2</p>

  <button>Слово3 Слово4</button>
  Слово5 Слово6
</div>
```

Я немного усложнил задачу, так как текст можно вытащить проще если он лежит первым в элементе, а вот если между текстом есть еще элементы это уже сложнее:) Поэтому я добавил Слово5 и Слово6.